# How to keep specific old kernels around after a yum update

Tags: centos6, yum, kernel, grub

I know that in CentOS 6.x, you can put the following line in /etc/yum.conf which tells yum to keep the last N kernels (by default this is set to five):

```
installonly_limit=5
```

However, there are cases when using experimental kernels (such as from ELRepo) where I want to keep a specific kernel around even if there have been 5+ updates to that kernel's package.

Are there edits to be made to /boot/grub/grub.conf or are there configuration options for yum (or dracut) to do this?

Comment: yum will never select to remove _the running kernel_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have yum version 3.2.26 or above and if you don't have it install yum-utils package which comes with the yumdb script. Using yumdb you can set a certain package to be kept from being removed on updates.

```
yum update yum
yum install yum-utils
yumdb set installonly keep kernel-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.x86_64
```