# How to keep a specific version of an old kernel while still allowing updates?

Tags: fedora, kernel, update, dnf

I need to keep an old kernel in Fedora: `kernel-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64`
But I still want the latest kernel updates.

1) A naive approach is to change the `installonly_limit=3` value to a high number in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`.

2) A [better solution](https://serverfault.com/a/652418) was to use `yumdb` to avoid automatic removing of the specific kernel:

```
yumdb set installonly keep kernel-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64
```

But the `yum` package manager has been replaced with `dnf` and there is no `dnfdb` command...
I have tried adding the following line to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` with no luck:

```
installonlypkgs=kernel-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64`
```

How to keep a specific version of an old kernel while still allowing updates?

Answer (score 3):

I think dnf mark is the command you are looking for. It marks the package as "user installed" protecting it from autoremoval.

```
dnf mark install kernel-4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64
```

https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#mark-command-label

There is also a dnf protect.d directory where you can store packages that shouldn't be removed. `/etc/dnf/protected.d`. However I have seen some people report this doesn't work with specific versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have tried `dnf mark`. Unfortunately, `dnf` still try to remove the kernel while updating.

I'm gonna look into the `protected.d` solution.

Comment: Since each kernel is a different package I don't see this working as you would want. It might keep it around but that doesn't mean it will keep it in use or listed. That might be a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : no kernel updates since the versionlock has been applied... Still looking for a solution !

I have found the `versionlock` dnf plugin which seems to eventually answer my problem:

```
sudo dnf install python3-dnf-plugins-extras-versionlock
```

According to [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/boot-earlier-kernel/) and [there](https://www.perl.com/article/prevent-harmful-updates-with-versionlock/), the following commands should do the job in my case:

```
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-4.14.18-300.fc27*
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-core-4.14.18-300.fc27*
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-modules-4.14.18-300.fc27*
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-modules-extra-4.14.18-300.fc27*
sudo dnf versionlock add kernel-devel-4.14.18-300.fc27*
```

Comment: Are you **sure** `dnf versionlock` actually worked for you, _including_ the "But I still want the latest kernel updates" requirement? In my testing just now, on F30 with `5.2.11`, `5.2.13`(booted), and `5.2.14` installed, setting `dnf versionlock add kernel{,-modules,-core,-devel,-modules-extra,-debug-devel}-5.2.11-200.fc30` prevented me from getting _any_  further updates. In fact, I couldn't even manually `dnf remove kernel\*-5.2.14-200.fc30`, `dnf` reported "No match for argument". Any attempts to upgrade to the (available) `5.2.15` were also ignored, until I deleted the versionlocks.

Comment: Indeed, no kernel update since a long time :-( I was pretty sure it was working, seems like I have missed something.

Comment: This [just came up](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-prevent-kernel-updates/3001) on the new Ask Fedora discord, some users (including myself) posted some ideas there.